# How to authenticate to AWS-KMS via the AWS SDK for JavaScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I am following the official example code for AWS SDK: https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-javascript/blob/master/modules/example-node/src/kms_simple.ts and try to encrypt and decrypt data using an AWS-KMS managed key.

However, I am curious how to authenticate with my AWS KMS account that Amazon knows, who I am  and that I have access to my keys?

Code:

```
import { buildClient, CommitmentPolicy, KmsKeyringNode } from '@aws-crypto/client-node';

const generatorKeyId = 'arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:464646464:alias/EncryptDecrypt';
const keyIds = [];

const keyring = new KmsKeyringNode({ generatorKeyId, keyIds });

console.log(keyring);

const context = {
  stage: 'demo',
  purpose: 'simple demonstration app',
  origin: 'us-west-2',
};

/* Create a string to encrypt */
const cleartext = 'my-test-string';

const { encrypt, decrypt } = buildClient(CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_REQUIRE_DECRYPT);

const { result } = await encrypt(keyring, cleartext, { encryptionContext: context });
console.log("RESULT", result)
```

I think I have to leave my AWS-credentials somewhere here, but where? The Documentation is not telling at all about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To learn how to get up and running with the AWS SDK for JavaScript v3, please refer to the official ***AWS SDK for JavaScript Developer Guide***. You will learn how to configure it -- including how to setup your credentials. See:

[Configuring the SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/configuring-the-jssdk.html)

In addition, the official Github location for AWS SDK code examples is here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples

Reading the ***JavaScript Dev Guide*** is the place to start to learn how to work with this SDK.